# Delphi IDE Menu integration - INTAServices

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2, vcl

I successfully installed my menu item inside Delphi using INTAServices40 but the problem is - menu is missing the next time Delphi starts?! Actually, two menu items are installed; One under Help menu which is ALWAYS shown (IOTAWizardMenu), but the one under Tools menu (TEST menu item) is missing the next time Delphi starts. How to fix this?

```
unit TESTMENU;

interface    
uses
   ToolsAPI, Classes, Windows, vcl.Menus, vcl.dialogs;    
type
   TCustomMenuItem = class(TNotifierObject, IOTAWizard, IOTAMenuWizard)
     function GetIDString: string;
     function GetName: string;
     function GetState: TWizardState;
     // Launch the AddIn
     procedure Execute;
     function GetMenuText: string;
   end;

   TCustomMenuHandler = class(TObject)
    // Handle custom menu
     procedure HandleClick(Sender: TObject);
   end;

procedure Register;

implementation    
var
  mnuitem: TMenuItem;
  CustomMenuHandler: TCustomMenuHandler;

procedure TCustomMenuItem.Execute;
begin
  ShowMessage('IOTAWizardMenu based menu item');
end;

function TCustomMenuItem.GetIDString: string;
begin
  Result := 'TMS.MenuSample';
end;

function TCustomMenuItem.GetMenuText: string;
begin
  Result := 'IOTAWizardMenu';
end;

function TCustomMenuItem.GetName: string;
begin
  Result := 'TMSMenuSample';
end;

function TCustomMenuItem.GetState: TWizardState;
begin
  Result := [wsEnabled];
end;

procedure TCustomMenuHandler.HandleClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('INTAServices40.MainMenu based menu item');
end;   

procedure AddIDEMenu;
var
  NTAServices: INTAServices40;    
begin
  NTAServices := BorlandIDEServices as INTAServices40;

  // avoid inserting twice
  if NTAServices.MainMenu.Items[9].Find('TEST') = nil then
  begin
    CustomMenuHandler := TCustomMenuHandler.Create;

    mnuitem := TMenuItem.Create(nil);
    mnuitem.Caption := 'TEST';
    mnuitem.OnClick := CustomMenuHandler.HandleClick;
    NTAServices.MainMenu.Items[9].Add(mnuitem)
  end;
end;

procedure RemoveIDEMenu;
var
  NTAServices: INTAServices40;
begin
  if Assigned(mnuitem) then
  begin
    NTAServices := BorlandIDEServices as INTAServices40;
    NTAServices.MainMenu.Items[9].Remove(mnuitem);
    mnuitem.Free;
    if Assigned(CustomMenuHandler) then
      CustomMenuHandler.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  AddIDEMenu;
  RegisterPackageWizard(TCustomMenuItem.Create);
end;

initialization
  mnuitem := nil;    
  CustomMenuHandler := nil;    
finalization
  RemoveIDEMenu;
end.
```

So, my first problem is how to get menu item TEST shown each time Delphi starts.. Also, I would like to add icon next to the menu item TEST. Any directions?

Thank you

**EDIT:** 
I just found out my package is delayed loading. Reading the Internet people say   ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable) should be called. But, this is not helping me also....

Comment: OTA plugins have to be implemented as Packages that are installed into the IDE and loaded each time the IDE is run.  Assuming you did create a Package, did you verify that the Package is being loaded on the next IDE restart?

Comment: I did check it and it's loading. The problem is - menu item is not showing even if I manually add a package (bpl). Only when I recompile the package the menu item is shown.

Comment: Which version of Delphi is this?

Comment: The "Tools" menu is being built/rebuilt after your package is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`NTAServices.MainMenu.Items[9]` may return different things at different times as the IDE is loading its packages, also there are menu items whose sub-items are managed by the IDE at runtime (e.g. the Window menu).

You could look up the Help menu item component by name:

```
procedure AddIDEMenu;
var
  HelpMenu: TComponent;
begin
  HelpMenu := Application.MainForm.FindComponent('HelpMenu');
  if (HelpMenu is TMenuItem) and (TMenuItem(HelpMenu).Find('TEST') = nil) then
  begin
    CustomMenuHandler := TCustomMenuHandler.Create;

    mnuitem := TMenuItem.Create(nil);
    mnuitem.Caption := 'TEST';
    mnuitem.OnClick := CustomMenuHandler.HandleClick;

    TMenuItem(HelpMenu).Add(mnuitem);
  end;
end;

procedure RemoveIDEMenu;
var
  HelpMenu: TComponent;
begin
  if Assigned(mnuitem) then
  begin
    HelpMenu := Application.MainForm.FindComponent('HelpMenu');
    if HelpMenu is TMenuItem then
      TMenuItem(HelpMenu).Remove(mnuitem);
    mnuitem.Free;
    CustomMenuHandler.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is not working for me... The problem is menu item is not showing next time Delphi starts.

Comment: It worked for me. Try debugging to see what goes wrong in your case.